# Chars not adding as ints using atoi()?

Tags: c

I'm new to C. I have a very silly question, but I can't figure out this very simple bug in my code for generating combinations.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

void combinations (int v[], int start, int n, int k, int maxk) {
        int i;

        if (k > maxk) {
                
                for (i=1; i<=maxk; i++) {
                  int sum = 0;
                  sum += v[i];
                  printf("%d", sum);
                }
                
                printf ("\n");
                return;
        }
        
        for (i=start; i<=n; i++) {
                v[k] = i;
                combinations (v, i+1, n, k+1, maxk);
        }
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
        int v[100], n, k;
        n = atoi (argv[1]);
        k = atoi (argv[2]);
        combinations (v, 1, n, 1, k);
        exit (0);
}
```

If you run the code above using `./main 5 3`, you'll get the following:

```
123
124
125
134
135
145
234
235
245
345
```

What I was *trying* to do was print out the sum of the integer representations, not the concatenated characters - for instance, the first line should be `6`, not `123`. Unfortunately, I'm getting a weird error when ever I use `atoi()` on the line `sum += v[i];`, e.g. `sum += atoi(v[i]);` throws an error. I know I can't really use `atoi()` because I don't have a pointer, but I'm not sure how to resolve this problem. Using `int(v[i])` doesn't throw an error, but it also doesn't fix the problem.

I'd greatly appreciate if someone could 1) tell me why `atoi()` isn't appropriate here/how I'm using it wrong and 2) how I can get each element of each combination to be treated as an integer.

Comment: You are not initializing the array with any data. This is undefined behaviour.

Comment: Avoid the use of `atoi()` instead use either `sscanf()` or `strtol()` which have at least minimal error detection. You can write `atoi ("cow");` and it will happily return `0` without any indication of a failure...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following loop is resetting `sum` on every iteration, so all it's doing is adding `v[i]` to `0` each time.  It's also printing `sum` on every iteration, rather than once at the end:

```
for (i=1; i<=maxk; i++) {
    int sum = 0;
    sum += v[i];
    printf("%d", sum);
}
printf ("\n");
```

Just change it to:

```
int sum = 0;
for (i=1; i<=maxk; i++) {
    sum += v[i];
}
printf("%d\n", sum);
```

Comment: Not to mention the limits of `i=1; i<=maxk; i++` looking very suspicious. May be fine, but sure looks like the old common-minstake on not understanding zero-indexed arrays.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Yes, the indexing is nonstandard, but it appears to be consistent.

Comment: Yes, as long as the parameters are less than 99 all is fine, but it still gives me the creeps `:)`